# Best place/way to buy masses of bricks

Tags: shopping

I am always having to take apart models I made to make new ones :'( and it really is bugging me.

I don't want to buy specific sets, as they cost a lot because of the work that went into designing them and the licensing, but I want more bricks.

Is there a good site that sells massed bricks in certain colors? I know of Pick-A-Brick, but I was wondering if there were any others.